# How to find the maximum number in a list with numbers and strings in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list which contains a word and three different numbers. I want to find a way to select the largest of these three numbers, but whenever I use the max function it selects the word instead. Is there any solution to this?

Part of my code goes as follows:

```
myList = list()
userName1 = input('What is your name?')
myList.append(userName1)
score1 = input('User 1 score 1')
myList.append(score1)
score2 = input('User 1 score 2')
myList.append(score2)
score3 = input('User 1 score 3')
myList.append(score3)

print(max(myList))
```

For these, I inputted my name (Daisy) and three numbers (6, 9 and 4). I hoped that the max function would select the 9, but instead it printed Daisy.

Comment: Can you post a working code example?

Comment: sample input and output to that would be nice

Comment: So it is actually a list of all strings, but some of the strings represent numbers.

Comment: max of list of String gives the longest String in the list hence the `Daisy`

Comment: Updated it with an example of my code @Alex

Comment: do you need to append the user name? can't you just append the scores? also the scores you appended are strings, they need to be converted to numbers to find the maximum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested suggestion to improve code as a whole:

```
userName1 = input('What is your name?')
scores = input('User scores, comma seperated')
print("user %s has max score %d"%(userName1, max(map(scores.split(','),int))))
```

Answer (score 2):

`input()` returns a string holding the user's input. You need to convert your strings to integers (the ones that can be), so you could build a new list of these numbers and find the maximum of that one. This is a good use of the `try...except` clause: just ignore (`pass`) the exception you get if you try to convert something like `'Daisy'` into a number.

```
In [1]: myList = ['one', 1, 'foo', '4', '5', '2']

In [2]: numbers = []

In [3]: for item in myList:
   ...:     try:
   ...:         numbers.append(int(item))
   ...:     except ValueError:
   ...:         # ignore items which aren't integers
   ...:         pass
   ...:     

In [4]: max(numbers)
Out[4]: 5
```

At the moment you're comparing string values, which will not give you the necessary maximum even when the string can be converted to integers (e.g. '10' is "less than" '9').

Comment: After the String to Int cast `print(max([i for i in myList if isinstance(i,int)]))` is much better way

Comment: @AnkurAnand But OP's `myList`, as coded, will contain _only strings_: i.e. `['Daisy', '6', '9', '4']`.